# check if button type=submit name=submit has been clicked in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i am trying to get which button is clicked from a form. I have 3 buttons in a form here is how my view looks like:

```
<div class="form-actions">
  <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn green"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Submit</button>
  <button type="submit" name="draft" class="btn btn-warning"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o"></i> Draft</button>
  <button type="submit" name="Trash" class="btn red"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Trash</button>
</div>
```

And here is how i am checking that on my controller:

```
  if(Button::get('submit')) {
  $request['status'] = 1;
}
elseif(Input::has('draft')) {
  $request['status'] = 2;
} else {
  return "something else"; //i am ending us with this all the time.

}
```

I am always **ending up with `something else`**. when i do the `return $request->except('_token');` i get this:

```
{
  "pagename": "asdfasdf",
  "pagecontent": "<p>asdfasdf<\/p>\r\n",
  "displayfrom": "2016-02-04 00:00:00",
  "submit": "",
  "metatitle": "",
  "metakeywords": "",
  "metadescription": "",
  "user": 11,
  "active": 1
}
```

I dont know why its not getting the value of a `<button type="submit">`.

Any suggestions will be helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this in submit button `value="submit"`

```
<button type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" class="btn green">
<button type="submit" value="draft" name="draft" class="btn btn-warning">
```